# Input resultando em None

Tags: python

Eu estava tentando um novo de apresentar os textos em um jogo básico que eu estou criando, que basicamente da uma sensação de que o texto esta sendo escrito
O código é esse abaixo:

```
def print_slow(txt):
    for x in txt:                     
        print(x, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.02)
    print()
print_slow("Olá, o dia está belo hoje")
```

eu não entendo muito sobre funções, mas sempre que eu tento colocar essa função em um *input* como:

```
input(print_slow("Olá, como vai?:"))
```

ele funciona como deveria, só que aparece um *None* na onde você iria escrever:

```
Olá, como vai?:
None
```

alguem sabe por que isso ocorre, e se tem alguma forma de colocar um *input* com essa função que deixa o texto "lento"??

Comment: Retire o `print()` depois do loop e veja o que acontece

Comment: @Wilson Bonato eu quero do fundo do meu coração te agradecer por você fazer essa pergunta. Porque eu nunca tinha pensando em criar um print devagar e você abriu minha mente para ter várias ideias de programas legais para criar. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque a sua função não possui um retorno e automaticamente o Python devolve `None` ao chamar a função.

**Corrigindo o problema:**

Você deseja escrever o seu código de forma que o usuário possa digitar na mesma linha da impressão ? Exemplo:

```
Olá, como vai?: Vou bem.
```

Se sim, primeiro você deve retirar o último `print()` da sua função para impedir a quebra de linha. Depois disso, separe a chamada do `print_slow()` e `input()` em linhas diferentes para que o retorno *None* da sua função não seja passado como parâmetro. Exemplo:

```
import time

def print_slow(txt):
    for x in txt:                     
        print(x, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.02)

print_slow("Olá, como vai?")
answer = input(": ")
```

---

Se por algum motivo, você não deseja fazer todas essas alterações no seu código, você pode fazer de outra forma que eu não recomendo muito, mas também pode solucionar o problema. Essa forma é basicamente definir uma string vazia no retorno da sua função. Exemplo:

```
def print_slow(txt):
    for x in txt:                     
        print(x, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.02)
    print()
    return ""
```

Isso corrige o problema, pois ao retorna uma string vazia, ela será passada como parâmetro para o `input()` e o usuário não verá nada, pois a string está vazia.

E porque eu não recomendo muito ? Porque não faz sentido sua função retornar uma string vazia, ainda mais sendo uma função para imprimir texto.

Answer (score 1):

isso acontece pelo fato da sua função `print_slow()` retorna o valor `None`, simples assim.
e o `input()` também mostra um valor na tela, junto ao valor que o print_slow retorna que é 'None' já que não retorna nada

tem dois jeito que imagino em corrigir, citarei abaixo

### Opção 1

retirar o print_slow de dentro

```
def print_slow(txt):
    for x in txt:                     
        print(x, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.02)

print_slow("Olá, como vai?: ")
x = input()
```

### opção 2

alterar a função

```
def print_slow(txt, perg: bool = False):
    for x in txt:                     
        print(x, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.02)
    if perg:
        input()
        print()
    else:
        print()

print_slow("Olá, o dia está belo hoje")
print_slow("Olá, como vai?: ", True)
```